# Any idea why Google not caching my site?

Tags: cache, google

My site www.books-for-children.com (developed in Wordpress) has been live for about two months and still has not been cached by Google, which seems highly unusual. Any ideas why?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic for this site. But since I know the answer (which is very simple), I am posting my answer. **Please [read the FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) before posting a question.**

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the source code of the site and found this:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir,noarchive,nosnippet"/>
```

Apparently `noarchive` tells Google to not cache the page. Check out [Google Webmaster Tools documentation/guidelines for "Meta tags"](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812) for more info on what each value does.

**PS:** If you are unaware, `nosnippet` should also be removed as it "prevents a snippet from being shown in the search results".

So, it's best to remove the meta tag completely, as it's not necessary, or modify it to this:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir" />
```

Comment: Thank you!! Oddly, this was a setting in Yoast SEO, which you would think would do the opposite. Not sure if it was a default setting or one that a developer messed up. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Why so quick to close a topic that is all about a Wordpress setting, specifically a plug-in setting? I don't get it, especially when the answer was so correct, so helpful, and information that was not easily found elsewhere. Under those circumstances where your site is so effective and beneficial, it's hard to understand closing the question.

Comment: @Dan This site is for WordPress-**specific** issues. Although your problem was caused by a plugin, your question "why aren't my pages being cached by Google?" *in a way* could happen with any web page, and is thus not wordpress-specific. Besides there was no mention of a plugin in your question, or my answer. :P